# How to use common master page for C# and VB.NET WebForms sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, master-pages

### The problem

I have two projects: one is C# WebForms application (child) based on .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012), second is VB.NET WebForms app (parent) running .NET 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010). What I need is to use Master page from parent project (including all code behind and controls embedded in Master), session state and authentication info in child.

### What I've done

I think it may be possible by creating virtual directory in parent site containing child project and linking to parent masterpage directly. When I tried it, I've got unresolved reference errors, which I've tried by adding parent DLL as referenced to child project.

I suppose it may be possible to have common authentication info and session state) when running two distinct sites under single domain, it can be handled by virtual directory and session state stored in separate process or in SQL. Still, there is problem with Master containing some logic (mainly common layout/controls) which I'm unable to bind into new project so far. I don't even know where to look and what to try next.

Is there any possibility to glue those two projects with common Master page template without rewriting one of those as part of another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a built in facility to do this within asp. the fact that one is in C# and one is in VB.NET doesn't really matter though.

This might help - there is some info towards the bottom of the page regarding sharing master pages.

http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx

Hope this helps....

Comment: I checked it, also tried various other tricks and there's no way to use common non-trivial masterpage in two separate web applications.